# iPhone localStorage trace method

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, cordova

I know about apple recommendation of localStorage in iPhone, but it is my job right now to use it any way.

My question is how I can trace the localStorage of iPhone? How can I check what is in it? something like resource panel of browser.

I am using cordova, iOS , iPhone 7.1

The bug I have right now: I am setting some localStorage records and put small texts or json strings in them an use them in other pages and they work very good in safari.

But some of those localStorage records do not set properly in iPhone and I do not see any error messages in Xcode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Safari Web Inspector to inspect your cordova app:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW1

> After Web Inspector is enabled, connect your device to your desktop machine with a USB cable. The name of your device appears in the Develop menu of Safari alongside all open inspectable apps and webpages.
>
> Alternately, you can use iOS Simulator to take advantage of Web Inspector’s debugging capabilities, which comes free with Xcode from the Mac App Store. Use the same instructions,“To enable Web Inspector on iOS,” from within the iOS Simulator’s Settings app.
>
> If you have a development provisioning profile installed on your device, you can even inspect the web content of any UIWebView object in your app. The name of your app will appear as a submenu under the name of your device. When debugging web content in a web view, Web Inspector behaves in the same manner as debugging web content in Safari.